# Design of a modular application

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, programming-practices, modules

I'm developing an application (Java) in a modular architecture. I have two approaches in mind and I'm not sure which one will be "better code" in case of maintenance and conventions.

I have two main modules that I want to wire them up:

1. `CORE` - backend stuff
2. `UI` - frontend stuff

I can think of two approaches:

- ***APPROACH 1:*** `CORE` module will expose `Engine` class, `UI` will expose `UserInterface` class.
  `UserInterface` will need an `Engine` in its constructor. Creation of both objects will take place in the third module called `LAUNCHER`.
- ***APPROACH 2:*** `CORE` module will expose `Engine` class, `UI` will expose `UserInterface` class. The difference is both modules with expose those classes ONLY to `PRELAUNCHER` module that will create objects and pass them to the `LAUNCHER` module as ***interfaces***.

The second approach looks promising, because it won't allow any module create the instantion of UI/CORE module classes (as Java offers sealed interface - that means I can choose which class can implement it). That's kind of dependency injection - the needed items will be created in one place and passed as interfaces.

On the other hand - the approach introduces more code - one more module and at least two new interfaces.

Any ideas which one is better in terms of maintenance and conventions?

Comment: Have you considered a standard dependency injection framework? How are the unit tests going to instantiate these things?

Comment: What is the advantage of not being able to create new engines and new user interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the names you assigned to your classes it does not seem the engine depends on the UI in any way. If the dependency is indeed one way (UI uses engine) there is no point in abstracting away the UI for any client to address it through a interface. You may be better of by just having the UI instantiate the engine and by focusing on making the engine's interface useful to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Modularisation aims to decompose a software into replaceable and reusable components that are based on well-defined interfaces.

**Approach 1** partially achieves this objective : `UserInterface` depends on a `Engine` via an implicit interface that encapsulates its implementation details.  You could therefore replace the implementation of `Engine` with another implementation or even a subclass of it.  But you are cannot reuse `UserInterface` independently of `Engine`.

**Approach 2** completely achieves the objectives of the modularization: according to your explanations `UserInterface` no longer depends on `Engine` but on an interface that abstracts away the engine and could easily be replaces with other implementations.

The use of a prelauncher and a launcher to further fine-tune accessibility control would of course enforce the proper use of the interface.  But it might be an overkill in your case:

- Instead, you may consider to just modularize the interface, i.e having an `EngineInterface` defined independently of the `Engine`, and that could safely be consumed by the `UserInterface` and the `Launcher`.  This would be simpler.  The launcher could still do the wiring as above since its goal is to make the glue between your modules and not be independent.
- Adding an `EngineFactory` to the interfaces could make sense if engines are constructed in a lot of places but seem not absolutely required in your context.